# Storing data in database pivot table Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have two tables with a many-to-many relationship that are joined by this table below

[image]

I am using the store method below within my controller but when called its returning an error: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'thought_journal_entry_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `thought_journal_entry_emotions` (`emotion_id`, `thought_journal_entry_id`) values (1, ?))

I understand that there's no id for the `thought_journal_entry_id`, but I'm not sure how to find it. When trying `$entry = ThoughtJournalEntry::find(1)` it works but I need to store data for new instances of the ThoughtJournalEntry `$entry = new ThoughtJournalEntry` How can I do this?

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'thought_entry' => 'required'
        ]);

        $entry = new ThoughtJournalEntry;
        $entry->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $entry['entry_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i');
        $entry->thought = $request->input('thought_entry');
        $emotions = $request->has('emotions') ? $request->get('emotions') : [];
        $emotions2 = Emotions::find($emotions);
        $entry->emotions()->sync($emotions2);
        $entry->tt_id = $request->has('thinking_traps') ? $request->get('thinking_traps') : [];
        $entry->balanced_thought = $request->input('balanced_thought');
        $entry->save();

        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first save the `ThoughtJournalEntry $entry` model in order to get the id. And then sync the emotions to the entry

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'thought_entry' => 'required'
        ]);

        $entry = new ThoughtJournalEntry;
        $entry->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $entry['entry_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i');
        $entry->thought = $request->input('thought_entry');
        $emotions = $request->has('emotions') ? $request->get('emotions') : [];

        $entry->tt_id = $request->has('thinking_traps') ? $request->get('thinking_traps') : [];
        $entry->balanced_thought = $request->input('balanced_thought');
        $entry->save();

        $emotions2 = Emotions::find($emotions);
        $entry->emotions()->sync($emotions2);

        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }
```